# Recursively find the lowest number in a list.

Tags: python, function, recursion

I wrote some code for my recursive functions homework. I want to find the smallest number in the list. Why doesn't this code work? For example, when I enter 2,-99, and 110 the program returns -99 but when I enter 2,5,-9 it returns 2. I can't understand what the problem is.

```
def rcompare(numList):
    end=len(numList)-1
    if(end==-1):
        return 0
    else:
        if (end!=-1):
            swapped=-1
            for i in range(0,end):
                if (numList[i]>numList[i+1]):
                    numList[i],numList[i+1]=numList[i+1],numList[i]
                    swapped=i
            end=swapped
            return numList[0]
numList=input("Please enter some numbers seperated by comma: ").split(",")
numList=[int(i) for i in numList]
print(rcompare(numList))
input()
```

Comment: This function is not recursive, it never [calls itself](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13992619/recursive-funciton-codes-dont-work-correctly#comment19312537_13992619).

Comment: @gecco The [tag:homework] tag is deprecated, please don't add it to new questions.  See the tag wiki and the meta post linked there for details.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, the function isn't recursive.

The main reason it doesn't work correctly is that it always returns the smaller of `numList[0]` and `numList[1]` (when you think about it, only the first iteration of your loop can affect the overall outcome).

If the smallest value is located further down the list, your function will never return it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would do it.

```
def lowest(l, low=None):

    if low == None:
        low = l[0]

    if l:
        if l[0] < low:
            low = l[0]
        del l[0]
        return lowest(l, low=low)
    else:
        return low



print lowest([2,-99,110])
print lowest([2,5,-9])
```

Comment: It might be worth noting that this has quadratic complexity (and also destroys the list).

Comment: As NPE pointed out this function isn't useful beyond an academic understanding of recursion. If you're actually interested in more efficient sorting algorithms check [this](http://en.literateprograms.org/Quicksort_%28Python%29) out, also quicksort is recursive.

Answer (score 0):

johnthexiii has the correct code. The reason why yours fails is because you're code compares the current item with the next item, and swaps those if next item is smaller. That doesn't guarantee the smallest item is first in the list. When your code finishes for [2,5,-9], the final list is: [2,-9,5]. Thus, blindly relying on numList[0] fails if the minimal value is numList[2] or later.

If you really want to just return numList[0], then you need a loop more like:

```
for i in range(0,end):
    if (numList[0]>numList[i]):
        numList[0],numList[i]=numList[i],numList[0]
        swapped=i
    end=swapped
    return numList[0]
```